# Why does compute bound work runs on a smaller amount of threads than IO bound work

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

Please watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1FbKiHYHcw)
from 5:15 - 5:46.

I was watching this on youtube and the guy was explaining about TPL. I'm very new to TPL, I have never heard of it before and I did some research and found out that it's a very complicated system that simplify the amount of threads and work to run on the machine. However, from timespan 5:20 - 5:46, he showed 2 examples that just completely stomped me. The first example was a compute bound work which he wrote a for loop that loops 350,000,000 times which took his computer approximately 1 second.  The second example was an IO bound work which he wrote Thread.Sleep(1000).

My question is why does the compute bound work he wrote uses only 2 threads and the IO bound work he wrote uses 5 or 6 threads?

Comment: I flicked through that video and saw no io bound work, however i must admit it was just a flick `thread.sleep` is not IO

Comment: I'll see if I find time to write a more detailed answer, but the trick is that the threadpool is smart enough to use the current CPU usage to decide the number of running threads. If overall CPU usage is low (Thread.Sleep), the computer is clearly able to process more stuff, so the threadpool starts new threads. If the overall CPU is high (the closed `for` loop), the threadpool knows that starting new threads won't help (since CPU is a finite resource)

Comment: @TheGeneral But Thread.Sleep still counts as IO bound work, right? Because, it spends most of its time waiting or rather, sleeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU-bound means that the CPU is busy calculating. So it makes no sense using more threads than cores available. More threads would mean that cores need to pause one thread to work on the other - with the additional switching this would *slow down* the total system.

For IO-bound work, the CPU is just waiting for the other system to respond. So in the meantime it can do other work. This is where async/await will shine.

Comment: ! CPU can only run on 1 thread, right? If so, that would mean the 5 or 6 threads running on a 2 core machine and the CPU have to do alot of context switches, right? Btw, Thanks for the answer